# I have edit button in notes.js file when I click on it 2 div's in createNote.js should toggle

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is notes.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Notes() {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([{
        title: '',
        content: '',
        _id: "",
    }])
    const [isPut, setIsPut] = useState(false);
    const [updatedItem, setUpdatedItem] = useState({
        title: "",
        content: "",
        id: "",
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/notes").then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setNotes(jsonRes));
    }, [notes]);

    function openUpdate(id) {
        setIsPut(true);
        setUpdatedItem(prevInput => {
            return (
                {
                    ...prevInput,
                    id: id,
                }
            )
        })
    }

    return (

        <div>
            <h1>notes</h1>
            {notes.map(note =>
                <div key={note._id}>
                    <h3>{note.title}</h3>
                    <p>{note.content}</p>

                    <button onClick={() => openUpdate(note._id)
                    }> <a href="/create">Edit</a></button>


                </div>
            )}



        </div>

    )
}

export default Notes
```

This is createNotes.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/Navbar.css"

function CreateNote(props) {


    const [input, setInput] = useState({
        title: '',
        content:''

    })
  
    function handleChange(event) {
       const {name, value} = event.target;

       setInput(prevInput =>{
           return{
               ...prevInput,
               [name]: value
           }
       })
    }

    function handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const newNote ={
            title: input.title,
            content: input.content
        }


        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/create', newNote  );
        alert("item added");

        setInput({
            title:"",
            content:"",
        });

    }

   



    return (
        
        <div className="notes_form">
            <h1>create note</h1>
           
            <form >
                <div>
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="title" value={input.title} autoComplete="off" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea onChange={handleChange} value={input.content}  autoComplete="off" name="content"  cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button onClick={handleClick} >ADD NOTE</button>
            </form>
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateNote
```

I know how to toggle two divs in same component but now I need to toggle form div in createnotes.js by onClick in notes.js

[image: This is notes.js image]

[image: this is createnotes.js]